# Can we reopen this question?

Tags: discussion

So, the original question didn't make the grade for the f.a.q. but it has since been revised and maybe revisited?

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44346/where-is-the-best-place-to-keep-current-on-rockstar-releases-particularly-on-an

Answer (score 5):

The revised question is still a poor fit for the site, because it's essentially [website-rec](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-rec).

The fact is, that we typically don't do very well with questions like "Where should I go to find out about ________" for the same reasons that we don't do well with "What game should I Play?" Both questions have most of the same problems.

Comment: I agree.  Which brings us to this question. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23944/where-can-i-find-an-item-value-guide-for-tf2

Comment: A website-rec does not automatically mean it's off-topic: see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2334/are-questions-asking-for-non-game-recommendations-off-topic. I agree this question is iffy, though.

Comment: then how should such a question be worded? It seems that finding out about game releases is a valid concern if for none other than budgeting reasons. not trying to make waves, I've just been active on a different site that has very different standards than gaming.

Comment: @Sarge in general, we don't do upcoming releases here. It's just not within our scope, and trying to massage a question about them to fit is counterproductive. It's not really a case of 'high standards' in this case - more one of deliberately narrow focus.

Comment: @lesspop I get that, but I read the OP as trying to ask like "I game on xbox live, where do I go to see the titles available?" just dealing with a particular game studio, I know the original scope of his question was off-topic but the other part of that seems definitive, answerable and with in the faq.